# Authentication with Vue/Electron Application

Tags: vue.js, electron, indexeddb

I'm building an application with Vue and Electron, and I'm wondering what the best approach is for authenticating users.

I'm using [JSStore](https://jsstore.net/) as a wrapper for IndexedDB as my database. I'm familiar with using `bcryptjs` as a means for authenticating users when I create Node backend and have traditional `/login` or `/signup` routes.

But this is where I'm starting to get confused. Do I need to set up a Node server to start up when my application starts up? Because given that I'm using IndexedDB, I don't know that it makes sense to have a process of `Sign Up --> Request to Node Server --> Send data back to browser`

Would I be better served using a different type of database? Could I do something such as adding `bcryptjs` to the Vue prototype, so that's it's accessible where I need it to work with JS Store? Are there security concerns that I should be aware of with an approach like that?

At this point I'm stuck, and have more questions than answers. I've done some looking around for articles, and I find a lot of content about setting up authentication with Vue, but not within the context of an Electron application. I'm not sure how that variable changes things.

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

JsStore is client side technology, which means if you are setting up authentication in client side, it will be available only to that device.

Let's understand it more by use case -

Say your application named `My Awesome app` has authenticaion implemented. User register it and then they are able to use it after registration. They are logging out and signing in again with registration data and everything is working normal.

Here is what wrong with this approach -

1. User buys another pc and installed application `My Awesome app`, he tries to login but unable to login because registration data does not exist on their new PC.
2. Due to some issue, user hard disk crashed & he installed new hard disk. Same thing as above he is not able to log in.

So it is recommended to implement the signin on some server & keep data there.